# Having a table with just the fields of the primary key is a conceptual error?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm designing a database which will store information about some artists. These artists can belongs to one or more organizations. From these organizations i just want to store their names and i'm thinking in create a table with these organizations which just have the names as primary key and nothing else. Is the fact of having a table with just the fieds of the primary key a conceptual error? In this case, i will appreciate some suggestions to solve that.

Comment: No, all is good here, as long as two organizations can not have the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an OrganizationId, to handle the situations where the Organization name changes.

You might also have situations where different organizations seem to have the same name.  How many "Museum of Modern Art"s are there?  (Well, to a New Yorker, only one ;-)

Your organization table might expand over time, with columns such as shortname, address, contact person, prefered language, and so on.  So, the table should look like:

```
 create table Organizations (
    OrganizationId int not null identity(1,1),
    Name varchar(255),
    CreatedBy varchar(255) default system_user,
    CreatedAt datetime default getdate()
)
```

In a mature database, you would even recognize that organizations change names, merge, and sometimes split.  You can handle this by adding effective dates and end dates to the records.

Comment: Ok, i think i'm gonna use something as this solution. Thanks, it was very useful.

Answer (score 5):

> Is the fact of having a table with just the fieds of the primary key a conceptual error?

Not by itself. There are perfectly legitimate situations where all fields comprise a PK.

In this particular case, the organization name *is* a key, but that doesn't necessarily mean it should be *primary* key - you could "invent" another key that is smaller (typically integer) and easier to maintain and make *it* primary, like this:

[image]

The `organizarion_id` is called a **"surrogate key"**, and some pros of doing that include:

- Child FKs will be slimmer (since only the integer is migrated to the child, not the whole string).
- You can update the `organization_name` without updating the `organization_id`, and consequently without cascading this update to children.
- A small integer surrogate may be friendlier to ORMs than a more complex natural key.

Cons:

- May require more JOINing.
- Requires one more index, and each additional index brings overhead (even in heap-based tables, but especially in [clustered tables](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index)).

As you can see, it's a matter of balance and you are the only one who has enough domain knowledge to make the right decision.

*NOTE: Order of fields in `organization_artist` matters. Use the order shown above if you need to efficiently query for artists of a given organization and reverse it if you need organizations of a given artist. If you need both directions, you'll need another composite index on these two fields (beside the index underneath PK), but in opposite order. If you can live with only one index, consider clustering this table (if your DBMS supports it).*

Answer (score 0):

The standard practice for something like this would be to have 1 table for the artists, 1 table for the organizations, and 1 association table to associate the artist with 1 or more organization.

```
ARTIST (id, firstName, lastName)

ORGANIZATION (id, name)

ARTIST_ORGANIZATION(artist_id, org_id)
```

Even though the organization name may/should be unique, it's good to have a numeric id as the primary key so you can do associations.  And querying the association with id is better performance than searching for a string.